# How to handle focus event of GWT TextInputCell?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a DataGrid with a column containing TextInputCell. When I focus on this cell a button must become active. In order to do this I have to catch some focus event.

TextInputCell API contains `onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater)`. Great, I could catch any event with this, I thought. But the first problem I ran at is that onBrowseEvent is thrown many times in a row when I loose/get focus.

It seems that this problem is typical, but I couldn't either come to or find any solution to solve this. I'd appreciate any help with it.

Here is where I'm going to catch "focus" event:

```
MyTextInputCell cell = new MyTextInputCell() {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
        //Event handling is expected to be here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ??

```
 String eventType = event.getType();
   if ("focus".equals(eventType)) {
       // dosomething           
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works (I'm new to events handling via `onBrowserEvent`)... but it throws approximately 6-7 "focus" events on one click. But I think it is better to suppress "extra focus events". It seems that this is the way TextInputCell works.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a cell preview handler and then check the event type against the constants defined in BrowserEvents